# Telerik Winforms RadGridView not filtering

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik-grid

I am trying to get the Telerik RadGridview control to filter, and am not having any luck. I am getting data back, and sorting is working. The FilterExpressionChanged is firing. Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Data retrieval:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    DataSet oDataSet = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(frm_Main.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            oConnection.Open();
            oCommand.Connection = oConnection;
            oCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ip.t_Dataload UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ip.t_Dataload_his ORDER BY Started DESC";

            using (SqlDataAdapter oDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oCommand))
            {
                oDataAdapter.Fill(oDataSet);
                radGridView1.DataSource = oDataSet.Tables[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form.designer.cs:

```
    // 
    // radGridView1
    // 
    this.radGridView1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Desktop;
    this.radGridView1.CausesValidation = false;
    this.radGridView1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
    this.radGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.radGridView1.EnableCustomFiltering = true;
    this.radGridView1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F);
    this.radGridView1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
    this.radGridView1.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.NoControl;
    this.radGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 24);
    // 
    // radGridView1
    // 
    this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AllowAddNewRow = false;
    this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AllowDeleteRow = false;
    this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AutoSizeColumnsMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.EnableCustomFiltering = true;
    this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.EnableFiltering = true;
    this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.SelectionMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
    this.radGridView1.Name = "radGridView1";
    this.radGridView1.NewRowEnterKeyMode = Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridViewNewRowEnterKeyMode.None;
    this.radGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
    this.radGridView1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
    this.radGridView1.ShowGroupPanel = false;
    this.radGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1277, 746);
    this.radGridView1.TabIndex = 2;
    this.radGridView1.Text = "radGridView1";
    this.radGridView1.EnableFiltering = true;
    this.radGridView1.RowFormatting += new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RowFormattingEventHandler(this.radGridView1_RowFormatting);
    this.radGridView1.CellFormatting += new Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellFormattingEventHandler(this.radGridView1_CellFormatting);
    this.radGridView1.CellDoubleClick += new Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventHandler(this.radGridView1_CellDoubleClick);
    this.radGridView1.DataBindingComplete += new Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(this.radGridView1_DataBindingComplete);
    this.radGridView1.FilterExpressionChanged += new Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewFilterExpressionChangedEventHandler(this.radGridView1_FilterExpressionChanged);
    //
```

Answer (score 3):

If you set

```
EnableCustomFiltering = true
```

and

```
EnableFiltering = true
```

filtering does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To make the filtering work, set `EnableCustomFiltering = false` and `EnableFiltering = true`.